# Installed Ubuntu to SSD; did I do it right? Laptop is a bit slow

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I recently removed my hard drive from my HP laptop, and installed a brand new SSD. When I did the installation type it asked me about setting up a partition. What could've been the proper way to have set that up?

Under the Installation Type it said:

> 1. free space ---1MB(Size)
> 2. /dev/sda1 : efi(Type) : 536MB(Size) : 33MB (Used)
> 3. /dev/sda2 : ext2(Type) : 115634MB(Size) : 10MB(used)
> 4. /dev/sda3 : 3860MB(Size) : Unknown(Used)
> 5. free space : 0MB(Size)

If I could re-install Ubuntu what would be the proper steps to do so?

Laptop is lagging a bit with a new SSD.
Current memory is 3.5 GiB.

Comment: Use ext4 not ext2. Otherwise if Ubuntu is on sda2 I can not see any problems with this info.

Comment: The ext2 is the default for /boot with LVM. Did you do a full drive install with LVM or LVM with encryption? But encryption should not slow it down much. And with 4GB of RAM, system should be normally running from RAM anyway. Once an app is loaded it says in RAM until bumped by full RAM and no use. So reuse of apps is often from RAM, not drive.

Comment: @oldfred I installed it without encrypting my home folder. if 3.5 is normal, then I suppose that it should be okay. I wasn't 100% sure. thank you so much

Comment: Good one @oldfred